# Django filtering results from database

Tags: python, django

I have a movie model that's supposed to filter by date.

```
qs = Movie.objects.filter(visible=True,).order_by('-hot', '-showing', 'name')
...
if self.kwargs.get('shortcut', None):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    shortcut = self.kwargs['shortcut']
if shortcut == 'now-showing':
    qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__gte=today,)
elif shortcut == 'today':
    qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__exact=today)
elif shortcut == 'coming-soon':
    qs = qs.filter(coming_soon=True, coming_soon_starts__gte=today)
elif shortcut == 'tomorrow':
    qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__exact=today + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
elif shortcut == 'this-weekend': #Friday - Sunday
    days = 4 - today.weekday()
    starts = today + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    ends = starts + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    qs = qs.filter(shows__starts__range=(starts, ends))
elif shortcut == 'tickets':
    qs = qs.filter( Q(shows__venue__name__icontains='imax') | Q( shows__venue__name__icontains='anga' ) | Q( shows__venue__name__icontains='century-cinemax-junction' ) & Q(shows__new_price__gte=100) & Q( shows__venue__name__icontains='anga' ))
```

on the `now-showing`, `coming-soon`, `this-weekend` filter correctly but `tickets` brings movies with expired start_date and price.
I need to edit it so it checks whether the start date and price are there then whether the venue is from the three cinemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
qs = qs.filter(Q(shows__new_price__gte=100), Q(shows__starts__gte=today), Q(shows__venue__name__icontains='imax') | Q(shows__venue__name__icontains='anga' ) | Q(shows__venue__name__icontains='century-cinemax-junction')
```

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

> If you provide multiple Q object arguments to a lookup function, the arguments will be “AND”ed together.